# Perform some calculation using kusto query

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have the following kusto query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "Tracker"
| project Id = tostring(customDimensions["Id"]),
          Rank = tostring(customDimensions["Rank"])
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

I need to calculate the total number of rows / total number of rows with Rank >= 1 (in this case, total number of rows = 2, total number of rows with Rank >= 1 is 1 so 2/1 = 2) in kusto query. How do I add this in the above kusto query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`countif()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countif-aggfunction).

for example:

```
customEvents
| where name == "Tracker"
| project Rank = tolong(customDimensions["Rank"])
| summarize result = count() / countif(Rank >= 1)
```